# Urgent need of help - I changed unsafe inodb_log_file_size mysql parameter and now fails to start

Tags: mysql

I made a mistake and changed the inodb_log_file_size parameter value in my.cnf without shutting down the mysql first and moving the ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1 out of directory. Now it fails to start, and can not see any logs (even they're activated, mysql don't log it).
How can i recover the data? Please help, it's a production server. Thank you!

Comment: Put everything back the way it was?

Comment: Puting all back and normally start it wont work :) I found the solution, you have to start the mysql with the size of the ib_logfile0 and inno_db_recovery mode 4

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all, I found the solution:

Run `ls -al /var/lib/mysql`, take the size of the file `ib_logfile1` and run the following:

```
/usr/sbin/mysqld -innodb_log_file_size={the previous length} -innodb_force_recovery=4
```

Then start mysql normally (everything should be fine now) and be sure you run the following:

```
mysqldump --all-databases > /i_am_stupid_make_a_complete_backup_today_2014_09_26.sql
```